# Dual Booting Windows & Linux with 7 different partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I have a 120GB storage device.
I plan on dividing it 60GB-60GB for 2 different operating systems.

I haven't tried this before and I'm afraid I'd lose important data, so here's what I'm trying to do.

Create 7 different partitions.
1 for Bootloader.
3 for 1 OS.
3 for the other OS.

Problem is, I can only create 4 primary partitions.

> Primary #1
>   Boot partition
>
> Extended #1
>   Root + User (for OS 1) (2 logical partitions)
>
> Extended #2
>   Root + User (for OS 2) (2 logical partitions)
>
> Extended #3
>   Swap + Swap (for OS 1 & 2) (2 logical partitions)

The only Primary partition (boot) will be used to boot into the 2 OS's with GRUB.

Will this be possible? Or will grub NOT DETECT the 2 different OS's because they're LOGICAL partitions from EXTENDED partitions??

And so what do I do if that was actually the case??

Comment: Why not just install the one os you want first of all with your seperate partitions for /  and home for your primary os then run ur other os’s from live usb or disk and offload the system to ram if need be  so u can remove your storage or keep the live usb image in and save sessions get a usb hub and have extra storage that or just use virtual machines I’m just curious

Comment: Why do you have two swap partitions?  Only one will be run at any one time, so only one will be using the swap partition at the time (unless you plan on having one hibernate and then run the other). If you won't be using the aforementioned hibernate situation, you need only a single swap partition (though if using a recent release of Ubuntu swapfiles can be used so you don't need a swap partition at all).  The four primary partitions also only applies to dos/mbr partitioning.

Comment: @guiverc you actually can use multiple swaps in parallel by giving them the same priority. The kernel will automatically distribute swapped pages to them, but that's only useful if the partitions are on separate drives. A single swap partition which is used by both OSs would use the least amount of disk space. 120GB is really little for two OSs IMO.